# How to add Sybase SQL Anywhere DB as linked server to MS SQL Server properly

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, sqlanywhere

I used the `Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Anywhere` to create a linked server, it shows remote databases and tables, I can read data, but writing data seems to work only using `OPENQUERY()` and when doing the *connection_authentication* using `EXEC ... AT ...` directly in the script.

- How can I have the SQL Server do the authentication automatically when opening a connection?
- How can I make normal write operations work without `OPENQUERY()`?

Sorry for not adding detailed error messages, I will add them later maybe, when I have access to the server again... But they were not meaningful anyway, i.e. when the weird authentication was missing, it just said "*could not insert*" or "*failed*" instead of indicating any authentication issue.

- How to get the real error messages that come from Sybase?

**Details:**

SAP Sybase SQL Anywhere 16 (OEM Authenticated Edition) <-> MS SQL Server 2014

```
EXEC 'SET TEMPORARY OPTION CONNECTION_AUTHENTICATION=''Company=...''' AT linkedserver
INSERT INTO OPENQUERY(linkedserver, 'SELECT column FROM table WHERE 0=1') VALUES ('')
```

...that's not nice.

**Even more details:**

[This is how I created the linked server](http://dcx.sybase.com/index.html#sa160/en/dbprogramming/pg-linked-server-script.html)

[This is the authentication I'm talking about](http://dcx.sybase.com/index.html#sa160/en/dbadmin/running-s-3420607.html)

Comment: Can you post the linked server definition? That's where you normally 'save' your authentication info. Here's a link to screenshot showing how top do it: http://www.sqldbadiaries.com/2010/10/22/generate-scripts-for-linked-servers/ Linked servers are notoriously unreliable. Perhaps you could explain the bigger picture here - why do you need communication between servers? Are you synchronising master data or something like that?

Comment: .. anmd does a basic `select * from linkedserver.database.schema.table` work?

Comment: Hi @Nick.McDermaid, may I assume that you think "authentication" is a username/password combination? That's forgivable :) However, it's some weird additional Sybase thing you have to do once after opening each connection. Since the connection is opened automatically on demand, I am looking for a good way. - Very bad to hear that linked servers are unreliable. So I better write an external application to copy data between MSSQL and Sybase? - Yes, I have to synchronize data between 2 different systems and hope that linked servers are comfortable for that. - Yes, selects work.

Comment: No I don't think authentication is just a user/pass. Looking at the links you posted it appears that the `SET` command that you need to run is required by SQL Anywhere OEM? and there is no way to embed it into a linked server, unless you can come up with a connection string that implements this you won't be able to automate it. I can't find any examples of SQL Anywhere connection strings. With regards to linked servers, you might find SSIS more useful. Linked servers require the external driver to be reliable and this is often not the case. SSIS is a bit better at handling unreliable drivers.

Comment: With regards to your synchronise, is one system the master? or are you merging between two? If you are merging between two, how do you deal with ambiguous things like the same record entered slightly differently in two systems? I only ask because if you can avoid the write on the SQL Anywhere side it would make things simpler for you

Comment: Hi @Nick, yes it's the OEM Authenticated Edition. I'll have a look at SSIS, but it seems much more complicated. I have to write data on both sides, but the structure is designed so that data synchronisation problems cannot happen - one side is the master and the other side sends only relative changes.

Comment: So if SQL is the master then yes you do need to write to SQL Anywhere. Yes SSIS is far more complicated - if you can get linked servers to be reliable then do it that way. The fact is, if you wrap your merge code up in a stored procedure, then adding an addition `EXEC` is not a problem. Sometimes you just have to live with these constraints and find your way around them. Your other problem about needing `openquery` to insert data. Are you saying that a straight `INSERT INTO` throws errors, even after you `SET TEMPORARY OPTION`?

Comment: Yes, straight `INSERT` and `UPDATE` statements threw errors, then I found the `OPENQUERY` solution and that worked. Now I tried again to give you the error message, but it worked! I have no idea... Thanks for your help.